# Visual Studio: Set same output directory for multiple exe projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, output

There are at least 2 exes projects in my solution, and they are supposed to be in the some directory after being deployed with some shared data file.

When I set output directory of all exe projets to folder W:\Cci, I got errors from a file named W:\Cci\Debug\net6.0.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs.
One error says "Error CS0579    Duplicate 'global::System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute'"
You can see that there is no project information in the file, so I guess all there exe projects wanted to output a file with same name to the dir and caused that error.

Btw, if I output them to different directory, everything is fine. But they just cannot find each other and work together.

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Copy output in post build event. Something like `COPY /Y "$(TargetDir)*.*" "C:\whereEver\"`

Comment: "But they just cannot find each other and work together." Does one reference the other as project-dependency? If so compiling the former will implictely also compile and copy the latter.

Comment: @Matyas I thought of copying. But I want to debug it when they are in the same directory.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain Yes and no. But both cause the error. :(

Comment: You might consider using some kind of build system. This might range from simple script files, to something like [Cake](https://cakebuild.net/). Or use a installer project for deployment, or use your CI system to gather artifacts into a single zip-file. There are many options.

Comment: @JonasH yes maybe. Now I just output them to different dirs and copy the exe to where they are deployed.

Comment: @cheny What data do these two `exe` files share? What do you want them to achieve? What does `But they just cannot find each other and work together.` mean? Why could'nt you add dependencies?